# vb.net DateTime.Now and next 15 mins

Tags: vb.net, datetime

```vb
 New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, Now.Hour, Now.Minute + 15, Now.Second)
```

im want to get time next now 15 mins but i use this code but don't work...

it will error if now more than "XX:46" pls help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date.Now().AddMinutes(15)`

It's better to use the built-in method of the Date type than to create a new New DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

You can do,

```
Dim MyDateTime AS DateTime
MyDateTime.Now().AddMinutes(15)
```

now you can use MyDateTime

i hope this help you

Comment: `AddMinutes` returns a new `DateTime`.

Comment: @minitech when assign 'Now' its return current datetime.

Comment: @JatinPatel - as minitech said, AddMinutes _returns_ a DateTime.  It does not alter the existing one.  You are calling Now() and then adding 15 minutes to it, but you are not storing the result anywhere.